# How do you link multiple markers on android studio google maps to websites when clicked?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been trying to link multiple markers to different websites but I don't know how. I tried the code below and the markers are showing but as soon as I click the one marker that I have set an intent for it doesn't work. I have seen a some other examples on stack overflow but nothing that helped me with this problem as they are mainly about just creating the markers. Please help!

```
public void addMarkers(){
    odeon = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ODEON).title("Odeon Cinema"));
    dublinrd = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(DUBLINRD).title("Movie House Cinema, Dublin Rd"));
    qft = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(QFT).title("Queen's Film Theatre"));
    strand = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(STRAND).title("Strand Cinema"));
    odyssey = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ODYSSEY).title("Odyssey Cinema"));
    kennedy = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(KENNEDY).title("Omniplex - Kennedy Centre"));
    cityside = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CITYSIDE).title("Movie House Cinema - City Side"));

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            if (marker.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Odeon Cinema")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.odeon.co.uk/films/"));
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
private HashMap cinemaMarker;
(it's better if you create a class cinema)

Then you can do:

```
     public void addMarkers() {
     //for each cinema
    cinemaMarker.put(googleMap.addMarker(cinema.getMarker()),cinema);
  }
```

And in you cinema class it will be something like:

```
public class Cinema {
    String name;
    String webSite;
    LatLng position;

        public Cinema(String name, String webSite, LatLng position) {
            this.name = name;
            this.webSite = webSite;
            this.position = position;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getWebSite() {
            return webSite;
        }

        public LatLng getPosition() {
            return position;
        }

        public MarkerOptions getMarker(){
            return new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(name);
        }
    }
```

So just before calling addMarker(), you can do something like this:

```
        List<Cinema> cinemas = new ArrayList<>();
    public void MockData() {
        cinemas.add(new Cinema("odeo",ODEO,"ODEON CINEMA"));
//[...] for each cinema you want;
}
```

and finally

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
cinemaMarker.get(marker).getWebSite));
                startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm guna try that now!